# Is there a simple way to find the parity of the remainder/quotient without performing the division?

Tags: number-theory, parity

The context is the following: I am performing some calculations on long integers in Montgomery form, and I need to know their parity without converting them back to normal form (which is slow). An integer $x \in [0; m)$ in Montgomery form is $x^\prime = (x R)\ \mathrm{mod}\ m$, where $m$ is an odd modulus, and $R = 2^k$. I wonder if there's a computationally easy way to find out $x\ \mathrm{mod}\ 2$ given only $x^\prime$

(To be more specific, I need to calculate $(a x + b y)/ 2\ \mathrm{mod}\ m$, where $a$ and $b$ are small integers, and $x$ and $y$ are long integers for which I only have their Montgomery form $x^\prime$ and $y^\prime$ - so I need to know the parity of $x$ and $y$ to apply corrections by 1. Or perhaps there's an easier way to do it?)

Comment: If all we are given is $xR\pmod m$, then no.  After all, $xR\equiv (x+m)R \pmod m$ and $x, x+m$ have opposite parity.

Comment: Well, I was hoping there's some trick with counting bits of $x^\prime$ or whatever. Unfortunately, such a question is hard to formalize and search for.

Comment: As I say, the parity is simply not determined.  With $k=1$, for instance, and $m=7$  We consider $x=2$ and get $x'=(2\times 2)\pmod 7=4$  But with $x=9$ you get $x'=(9\times 2)\pmod 7=4$ so just knowing that $x'=4$ does not tell you the parity of $x$.

Comment: Sorry, it's easy to forget what is implied in the specific area. When Montgomery representation is used, $x \in [0, m)$, so Montgomery representation is a bijection, and therefore the parity is determined too.

Comment: Ah, so you know $0≤x<m$.  So, then I agree $x$ is determined uniquely. So...maybe?  Looks hard, if the numbers involved are extremely large.  But maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate $\ \left(\frac{ax+by}{2}\right) \mod{m} $ from $\ a,b,x',y'\ $ and $\ m\ $ without needing to find the parities of $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $. You already have
$$ 
R(ax+by)\equiv ax'+by'\mod m
$$
and
$$
2\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)\equiv1\mod m\ .
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{ax+by}{2}\right)&\equiv\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)^{k+1}R(ax+by)\mod m\\
&\equiv\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)^{k+1}(ax'+by')\mod m\ .
\end{align}
If multiplication $\ \mod m\ $ is computationally easy, then the [square and multiply algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) makes the calculation of $\ \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)^{k+1}\ $ easy for any likely value of $\ k\ $.

Comment: Interesting, I thought I could avoid multiplying by $2^{-1}$ (which, even if efficient, is still noticeable), but I guess it is faster than direct conversion out of Montgomery form (especially seeing as how I can pre-calculate the inverse and use it multiple times).

Comment: The problem with this approach is non-mathematical: it's not easy to get access to `k`, since it is hidden in the depths of the bignum library and depends on the platform. But definitely something to consider.

Comment: If your software can easy calculate the Montgomery form of any input, you don't need to know $\ k\ $.  The Montgomery form of $\ 1\ $ is $\ R\mod m\ $ itself, and all you need to get $\ \frac{ax+by}{2}\mod m\ $ is the inverse $\ \mod m\ $ of $\ 2R\ $.